# BlueJ Error: Non-static method(OOPoint) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, oop, static, bluej

I'm a beginner java programmer; that is, I have no idea on the terms and stuff. Please refrain from using those programming terms, or at least define them in a way a clueless like me would comprehend.
So I'm trying to create a simple Point/Circle collision. I have to make the program print true if the point given is within the circle, or false if the point is outside or on the boundaries of the circle. I am required to have four classes. In one of my classes, I have this method `getX()` (Class OOPoint, the name). When I call this method in another class, I get the error. Please tell me what this error means and how I should fix it.
The code's below. I'm also not sure if it's entirely correct :/

```
    public class OOPoint
{
    double x;
    double y;

   public OOPoint(double x, double y)
   {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
   }

   public double getX(OOPoint point)
   {
       return this.x;
   }

   public double getY(OOPoint point)
   {
       return this.y;
   }
}
```

Comment: Where is the caller class? How you are accessing method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to call the method like this:

```
OOPoint.getX();
```

or maybe simply, from a main method within the OOPoint class:

```
getX();
```

which can only be used for a static method.

To get it to work with the class you have, you first need to create a Point object, then call its `getX` method. For example:

```
OOPoint point = new OOPoint(2, 3); //create a new point object
double x = point.getX(); //x = 2
```

You can read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for examples of the difference between static and instance fields/methods.